# Why is my SafeResourceUrl coming up undefined in a method of the same class

Tags: angular, typescript

```
export class ClassName implements OnInit {

    url: string = "{{'content.url' | translate}}";
    urlSafe: SafeResourceUrl;

    constructor(public sanitizer: DomSanitizer, private translate: TranslateService) { }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.translate.stream('content.url').subscribe((text: string) => {
            this.urlSafe = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(text);    


            console.log(this.urlSafe);//logs the SafeResourceUrl Object

            this.DoAThing();
        });

        
        
    }

    DoAThing() {

        console.log(this.urlSafe); //undefined

    }    
}
```

how come in this class, in `ngOnInit`, i can log the `SafeResouorceUrl` object

but i cannot for the life of me, figure out how to access the URL from that object in the below method.

granted DoAThing code could be run in ngOnInit, but i need to run it this way for a reason and cannot figure out why i get undefined.

what am i doing wrong in this class? Angular newbie, thanks for the support!

Comment: It should not be undefined. What happen when you pass the ```this.urlSafe``` as an parameter of ```this.DoAThing()```

Comment: thats a good thought @ArunkumarRamasamy, if it works i'll let you know so you can answer the question and get credit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write like this & it will log your value but your code should also work.

```
export class ClassName implements OnInit {

    url: string = "{{'content.url' | translate}}";
    urlSafe: SafeResourceUrl;

    constructor(public sanitizer: DomSanitizer, private translate: TranslateService) { }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.translate.stream('content.url').subscribe((text: string) => {
            this.DoAThing(text);
        });
    }

    DoAThing(url) {
        this.urlSafe = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(url);    
        console.log(this.urlSafe);//logs the SafeResourceUrl Object
    }    
}
```

Comment: you are right. in my code i am calling `DoAThing()` parameter-less and referring to the property urlSafe, but i can't post all the code so i tired to complete a simple example. i actually have an event listener calling `DoAThing()` and i figured out if i bind that to the class everything works. alternatively you can pass the param directly to the function and it will work. giving you credit for answering.

Answer (score -1):

Your function:

```
DoAThing() {

    console.log(this.urlSafe); //undefined

}
```

Is not bound to `this`. So to invoke it you must `someSafeResourceUrl.DoAThing`.

Alternatively use an arrow function:

```
DoAThing = () => {

    console.log(this.urlSafe); // this will always be bound

}
```

## More

- [`this` in TypeScript](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FR9mt_ZO2HA)

Comment: He is calling the DoAThing inside arrow function, so this context should be exist